# Place div below absolut div with variable hight

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 2 div's that need to stay side by side. For this I placed the first one absolut and just added a margin-left to the second one. This works.
But I have the problem that both can have different hights and the element below always needs to be below the highest one.

```
<div id="header">
    The header
</div>
<div id="contents">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   The footer
</div>
```

​
This is the whole code in fiddler:

http://jsfiddle.net/qPtXL/17/

How can I solve that without Javascript? And adding a margin-top to the footer didn't work either, cause I don't know how high the contents are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qPtXL/18/)

html:

```html
<div id="header">
    The header
</div>
<div id="contents">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   The footer
</div>
```

css:

```css
#header {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#contents .sidebar {
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    background-color: gray;
}

#contents .body {
    margin-left: 120px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#footer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.clear { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with floats and an item set to clear both sides

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPtXL/19/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link to a css only layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm) that has a 2-column style in this manner. There is also layout there for stacked columns in this nature as well. The reason you're having difficulty is because of the absolute element. By adding the absolute attribute, you've removed that element (and its height/width) from the collection of block elements in that container. It will stay relative to the container, but it will no longer impact any of the surrounding elements. It will also not impact the container itself (such as making it taller). You'll need to get a little more thorough with the usage of your containers in applying this positioning so that the elements stretch the container independently without losing their positioning with respect to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```css
#header {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}

#footer {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}

#contents {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float;
    left;
}

#contents .sidebar {
    height: auto;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```